# How to create new users in home partition?

Tags: linux, partitioning, fstab, debian-buster

I reinstalled Debian 10 on my computer where my home users directory is in a separate partition. Then I mounted automatically adding the last line:

```
# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=A8F4-8A13                            /boot/efi      vfat    defaults,noatime 0 2
UUID=86dcf31c-9657-43e1-84e2-d8a4ca6d69d3 /              ext4    defaults,noatime 0 1
UUID=eff68550-9a1e-4281-bfc1-a45f757959cc swap           swap    defaults,noatime 0 2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ed2f56a2-d53c-45d5-ba21-d5f7ed68e5d1 /home auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Now I need to link my user account (john) with the /home/john directory. And the new users must be created in home partition too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way, edit /etc/passwd and modify the uid and home directory as required.

Any new users home dirs are created with useradd and the -m switch.